How to add new WooCommerce Product Stock Statuses that behave as Out of Stock
I need to enable 2 new custom stock statuses in WooCommerce ("Available soon" and "In-store only"  - I have enabled the 2 new statuses, but my issue is that I need both of the new statuses to behave as Out of Stock (so disable the add to cart button etc).
I have used How to add custom stock status to products in WooCommerce 4+ answer code, to enable 2 new custom product stock statuses in WooCommerce:

"Available soon"
"In-store only"

Those new stock statuses are shown on the front end when selected, but they behave as in-stock products.  I will like they behave as Out of Stock instead so the products appear as out of stock on the front end - no add to cart option.
How to add 2 new WooCommerce Product Stock Statuses that behave as Out of Stock

You can use additionally woocommerce_product_is_in_stock filter hook for that, like:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 'filter_woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_product_is_in_stock( $is_in_stock, $product ) {
    if ( in_array($product->get_stock_status(), ['available_soon', 'in_store_only']) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $is_in_stock;
}

Making some little changes and optimizations to your existing code, like:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_stock_status_options', 'filter_woocommerce_product_stock_status_options', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_product_stock_status_options( $status ) {
    $status['available_soon'] = __( 'Available soon', 'woocommerce' );
    $status['in_store_only']  = __( 'In-store only', 'woocommerce' );

    return $status;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {
    // Get stock status
    switch( $product->get_stock_status() ) {
        case 'available_soon':
            $availability['availability'] = __( 'Available soon', 'woocommerce' );
            $availability['class'] = 'out-of-stock';
            break;

        case 'in_store_only':
            $availability['availability'] = __( 'In-store only', 'woocommerce' );
            $availability['class'] = 'out-of-stock';
            break;
    }
    return $availability; 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html( $stock_html, $product ) {
    // For variable products
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $available_soon = $in_store_only = $other_statuses = 0; // Initializing

        foreach( $product->get_available_variations('objects') as $variation ) {
            $_stock_status = $variation->get_stock_status(); // Get variation stock status

            // Count statuses
            if ( $_stock_status === 'available_soon' ) {
                $available_soon++;
            } elseif ( $_stock_status === 'in_store_only' ) {
                $in_store_only++;
            } else {
                $other_statuses++;
            }
        }

        if ( $available_soon > 0 && $in_store_only === 0 && $other_statuses === 0 ) {
            $stock_status = 'available_soon';
        } elseif ( $available_soon === 0 && $in_store_only > 0 && $other_statuses === 0 ) {
            $stock_status = 'in_store_only';
        } else {
            $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
        }
    } 
    // Other product types
    else {
        $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
    }

    switch( $stock_status ) {
        case 'available_soon':
            $stock_html = '<mark class="outofstock">' .  __( 'Available soon', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            break;
        case 'in_store_only':
            $stock_html = '<mark class="outofstock">' . __( 'In-store only', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            break;
    }
    return $stock_html;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
You will get something like:

